# Fetch request failing for DELETE method even though CORS headers are present

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch

I am trying to make a Cross Origin delete request via fetch and its failing with a 403 (Exact Error `Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:1180/api/deleteResource/name/something/city/Shenzhen%202' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.`)

Here are my request and response headers -

```
General -
Request URL: http://localhost:1180/api/deleteResource/name/something/city/Shenzhen%202
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 403 FORBIDDEN
Remote Address: [::1]:1180
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers-
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,Content-Length,Server,Date
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, CONNECT, OPTIONS, TRACE, PATCH
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Length, Server, Date
Content-Length: 43
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 18 Nov 2019 07:24:51 GMT
Server: Werkzeug/0.14.1 Python/3.6.5
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

Request headers-
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Access-Control-Request-Headers: access-control-allow-methods,access-control-allow-origin
Access-Control-Request-Method: DELETE
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:1180
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36
```

Whereas my GET requests are working just fine -

```
General - 
Request URL: http://localhost:1180/api/getResources
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:1180
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers -
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,Content-Length,Server,Date
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, CONNECT, OPTIONS, TRACE, PATCH
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Length, Server, Date
Content-Length: 6164
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 18 Nov 2019 07:24:44 GMT
Server: Werkzeug/0.14.1 Python/3.6.5
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

Request Headers - 
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:1180
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36
```

I do understand that the preflight check doesn't happen for Simple GET & POST requests due to which my GET is successful, but still I don't get why my DELETE is failing as it has been allowed from the server. Can someone help me understand what the problem here is?

Comment: Which language you are using for back-end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `DELETE` request has `access-control-allow-methods,access-control-allow-origin` headers, But In response, It only allows `Content-Type, Content-Length, Server, Date` headers. That's why it's throwing `doesn't pass access control` error.

**Solution**

Set `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` to allow `Content-Type,Content-Length,Server,Date,access-control-allow-methods,access-control-allow-origin`.

> **I am not sure about your `Back-End` technology, I can't provide code to allow above `headers` without knowing your back-end technology**